# How to create an archetype for my java maven project and upload it into GitHub artifact?

Tags: java, maven, github, artifact, archetypes

I developed a java maven project and published it to the GitHub. I'm using GitHub actions as ci/cd pipeline. Now I want to create an archetype of this project and publish it to the GitHub artifact, so that all other people in my team could use this archetype as base one whenever they are creating a java maven project. Generally we use `mvn archetype: create-from-project` to create an archetype. But I'm not getting the desired outcome. How can I achieve this? Anyone help me.

Thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Maven archetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500710/create-maven-archetype)

Comment: I tried it, but this is not what I'm looking for. my question is can we create and upload the artifact into github, and use that artifact in new project?

Comment: Yes - you can upload the artifacts and that archetype to a Git repo. Have someone download the archetype and use it in a new project. You will find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555460/how-to-add-a-maven-archetype-to-github) helpful in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for providing the resources, but with that implementation it will not adding files from the artifact. I want to implement like this https://cemerick.com/blog/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-ongithub.html